# Unzipping certain archives works on Windows but not on Linux

Tags: locale, zip

I've asked a few people and just thought about asking it here.  We get sent files from an international company for design work in a zip format.  Well when I run a script to unzip the files in the terminal, I receive a zip error **only** in Linux.  We can test, unzip, browse, and modify the files with 7zip and winzip all day.  When 7zip or Winzip is ran they do not indicate any security, too.

Terminal error:

```
compressed WinNT security missing (-7 bytes)
```

I've searched everywhere and find no solution or correction on this.  One collegue suggested,

> "using a different language version of Unzip could potentially change
>   the Unicode required to extract the file. Think of it like a password,
>   without the right code, you can't get in."

**Why in the Ubuntu terminal will unzip display an error?**

Comment: 7zip works on linux too.

Comment: Unicode is Unicode. It doesn't just "change" because of the locale. Your colleague is wrong.

Comment: What your colleague says has a grain of truth in it (zip doesn't specify a character set for filenames, so non-ASCII filenames can become garbled when extracted on a different system), but even that grain isn't relevant to your problem.

Comment: `7z` is the name of the command once installed. See `man 7z`.

Comment: Can you upload one of those files somewhere?

Comment: @graphicsman Your question doesn't specifically describe what the problem is to be solved.  It's very possible for `unzip` to display an error message but still correctly decompress an archive.  So we have to guess:  Are you unable to decompress the archive?  Does decompressing work but display an error message anyway?  If so, is the problem with the error message that you are worried, or just annoyed?  Etc.  You're more likely to get a better answer if you edit your question again to provide much more clarification and specifics.

Comment: It might be possible to determine more specifics if you can tell us which program (including version) the file was created by and which version of `unzip` you are using (try: `unzip -v`).

Answer (score 2):

I've done some digging in the source code (unzip60 from Ubuntu raring, though I suspect older versions don't differ much).
The error in question is internally called `TruncNTSD` and defined in `extract.c:295`. Most uses of this message, as expected, are in `win32/win32.c` and indeed refer to NTFS security data, however there's only one place in the code where you should ever get this error outside of a win32 system (since you reported seeing it on ubuntu).

The place in question (`extract.c:2118`) is in a function called `TestExtraField`. As Wikipedia explains:

*.ZIP file format includes the extra field facility within file headers,
which can be used to store extra data not defined by existing .ZIP 
specifications, and allow compliant archivers not recognizing the fields
to safely skip the fields.*

That's indeed what NT does to store security information. Importantly, the function printing the error comments

```
/* we know the regular compressed file data tested out OK, or else we
 * wouldn't be here ==> print filename if any extra-field errors found
 */
```

So if you can unzip the files themselves fine, it looks like this error is safe to ignore.
Looking further, the only place outside of win32 code that raises this error (assuming it's not a horrible bug in unzip) is `test_compr_eb:extract.c:2227`, which from a glance at the code looks like it occurs when **a zipped file has associated extra fields that are marked as compressed, but the field data has a length of 0 bytes.**

How this comes about I don't know - perhaps the program creating the zip files does this by accident, perhaps the extra fields are filtered out somewhere by security software. In any case, it looks harmless and probably has nothing to do with NT security at all. In conclusion, if your files unzip fine, **it's completely safe to ignore**.